# Running Python script inside bash script

Tags: python, bash

I have a small problem when I try to run a script in bash. First of  all , my script work well  when I run in terminal, but when I try to run by launcher in Ubuntu, I have this error

"`python: can't open file 'teste.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`"

My script is similar at :

```
 #! /bin/bash
 # This script use sample.py
 python sample.py games.txt
 sleep 15
```

Other informations :

```
Ubuntu 11.04
Python 2.7
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

From the error message it looks like you have to specify the full path to your script in the launcher.

Try adding the full paths to your command in your bash script, i.e. similar to:

```
   python /home/glc/sample.py /home/glc/games.txt
```

By the way, what is this file `teste.py`? In your post you refer to script `sample.py` - is this a different file? How does it connect? Did you possibly specify the wrong file name in the launcher?

Comment: Geraldo: For debugging, stick an `ls` and/or `pwd` in your bash script before calling the python file. This way you can see the directory contents and the current working dir.